# Java 7 reporting not installed?

Tags: java, android, openjdk, jdk

Okay, so I am trying to build an Android ROM, but the following error returns;

```
************************************************************

You are attempting to build with the incorrect version
of java.

Your version is: Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -javaagent:/usr/share/java/jayatanaag.jar
 java version "1.7.0_79" OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.5.6)
(7u79-2.5.6-0ubuntu1.15.04.1) OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.79-b02, mixed mode).
The required version is: "1.7.x"

Please follow the machine setup instructions at
 https://source.android.com/source/initializing.html
************************************************************
```

When executing `lunch aosp_grouper-userdebug`.

I've tried to install legacy versions of java 7 from the archive, but I have no idea how to install two versions of java 7 alongside when from a tar file.

Help?

Distro: Ubuntu 15.04

Answer (score 1):

In build/core/main.mk, the java_version_str contains the output of "java -version":

```
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -javaagent:/usr/share/java/jayatanaag.jar 
java version "1.7.0_79"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.5.6) (7u79-2.5.6-0ubuntu1.15.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.79-b02, mixed mode)
```

The java_version is supposed to extract "1.7.0_79" using grep. The caret at the beginning of the grep regular expression "^java" indicates that the author intended to be able to find a line starting with "java". Unfortunately, GNU Make variables do not store the line endings. So the grep only sees one giant line starting with "Picked".

The grep works accidentally when the "java version" happens to be on the first line. This is probably why "unset _JAVA_OPTIONS" was added in java_version_str, because it was causing similar problems.

The simplest solution is to follow the current band-aid solution by adding "unset JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS" to java_version_str:

```
java_version_str := $(shell unset _JAVA_OPTIONS && unset JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS && java -version 2>&1)
javac_version_str := $(shell unset _JAVA_OPTIONS && unset JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS && javac -version 2>&1)
```

The real solution would be to not use an intermediate variable java_version_str and perform the grep directly:

```
java_version := $(shell java -version 2>&1 | grep '^java .*[ "]1\.7[\. "$$]')
javac_version := $(shell java -version 2>&1 | grep '[ "]1\.7[\. "$$]')
```

Comment: What is `shell`?